# How to use "move..." verb to move sheets in Numbers?

Tags: applescript, applescript-numbers

I'm trying to figure out how to re-position sheets in Numbers. There is no way to insert things at specific location so I am hoping that I can find another way. The `move` verb drew my attention (it is in the Numbers dictionary) however there is little or no information, examples, usage scenarios or even what object types it works with.

Any insight in the context of the title?

Comment: The move in the Numbers dictionary is part of the Standard Suite, which typically works with files.  I have tried using it to move text items and tables from one sheet to another, but it always fails.  It is probably something they hope to provide functionality for some day.

Comment: @CraigSmith - Thanks, if you make it an answer I'll check it as solved, as unfortunate as that is. Not having ability to manipulate sheet orders is interesting miss on Apple's part.

Comment: Agreed.  This stuff happens to us AppleScript fans every time they re-work a major app.  We wait months to years before we get back the scriptability we had with the old app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move in the Numbers dictionary is part of the Standard Suite, which typically works with files. I have tried using it to move text items and tables from one sheet to another, but it always fails. It is probably something they hope to provide functionality for some day.